# how to save the userid in nsuserdefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsuserdefaults

When I login to my app with my email and password I am getting a response successfully at that time, to save my userid into `nsuserdefaults`, how can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)signInMethod
{
    NSString *accessKey = @"akjsda9s8dadandl4";
    NSData *returnData;
    returnData=[[WebServices alloc]loginTest:emailTxtFld.text andPassword:pswdTxtFld.text andSESSION_ACCESS_KEY:accessKey];
    if (returnData.length>0)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"SignIn response is %@",res);
        NSString *msg = [res valueForKey:@"userid"];
        NSLog(@"%@",msg);
    }
}
```

From the above code `WebServices` is my Service Class. How can I save that userid?

Comment: It's better practice to store sensitive data such as passwords in the Keychain instead of NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to save email and password and userIdto NSUserDefault.

```
 -(void)signInMethod
{
NSString *accessKey = @"akjsda9s8dadandl4";
NSData *returnData;
returnData=[[WebServices alloc]loginTest:emailTxtFld.text andPassword:pswdTxtFld.text andSESSION_ACCESS_KEY:accessKey];
if(returnData.length>0)
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"SignIn response is %@",res);
    NSString *msg = [res valueForKey:@"userid"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:emailTxtFld.text forKey:@"email"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pswdTxtFld.text forKey:@"password"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:msg forKey:@"userid"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"%@",msg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Store**

for store the `String` in `NSUserDefaults` you can directly use `setObject`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[res valueForKey:@"userid"] forKey:@"userid"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Retrieve**

for Retrieve the `String` in `NSUserDefaults` you can directly use `objectForKey`

```
NSString *Value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userid"];
```

**Remove UserdefaultValue**

if your work is over you want to clear the memory of userdefault use the following code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"userid"];
```

**Swift**

**Store**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(res["userid"], forKey: "userid")
```

**Retrieve**

```
 var Value: String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userid")
```

**Remove UserdefaultValue**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("userid")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply:) it is saving the userid bt not retriving the userid!

Comment: ok simple in this place **[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"userid"];** use **[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userid"];**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, instead of improving answer in comments, you would better edit your answer.

Comment: @Hemang -- tanx bro for your valuable information , Just wait I will modify

Comment: Thank you @Hemang and Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @MangiReddy, no problem. You can always accept an answer which helps you. You can see a check before the answer (under votes count). Just mark it as accepted. This will be more than a thank you for an answerer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 -(void)signInMethod
{
NSString *accessKey = @"akjsda9s8dadandl4";
NSData *returnData;
returnData=[[WebServices alloc]loginTest:emailTxtFld.text andPassword:pswdTxtFld.text andSESSION_ACCESS_KEY:accessKey];
if(returnData.length>0)
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"SignIn response is %@",res);
    NSString *msg = [res valueForKey:@"userid"];

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:msg forKey:@"userid"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    NSLog(@"%@",msg);
}
}
```

To retrive use

```
NSString *UDID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userid"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay:) it storing purpose right! i want retrieve the that userid  in other services like this                                              NSString *UDID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"userid"];
    NSData *returnData;
    returnData=[[WebServices alloc]contactUs:UDID andSubject:subTxtFld.text andMessage:bodyTxtView.text];
    if(returnData.length>0)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Contact response is %@",res); }

Comment: @MangiReddy edited the code